# How to resize a disk on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, disk

When I install the ubuntu 16.04 LTS in a virtual machine, I gave 21 GB for the physical space. Now, when I check the free space in my $home, I find 1.2 GB (on 10 GB)

[Like you can see it in this image , I have only a total of 10 GB in my disk, and only 1.2GB is free](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l48o3.png)

And when I check partitions using `fdisk -l /dev/sda` I obtained this : [result of fdisk in my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFjpF.png)

Now, because I don't have enough space in my disk (only 1.2 GB) I can't install some software that require more than that space. So, I want to resize my disk!

How can I do this!

Comment: You can show images directly by adding `!` in front. of the link (`![...](...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize partitions on a virtual machine the same as with a physical machine.  Make a backup, and then load GPartEd on a (virtual) live disc.